# Why after referenced dll files to my project they are not on my release directory when i build the project?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, dll, directx

When my brother is running the program he get exception say one or more of the dll files is not found.

I sent him the 3 dll files he tried to put them from where he was running the program he also tried to put them at the directory they are in my place:

> C:\Temp\dlls\DLL'S\Microsoft.DirectX.DLL

He created this directory and put them there but it didn't help.

I was sure once i referenced the dll files they are in my program no need to have them. And at least to have them in the directory where you running the program from but it's not working.

What i want is that my brother and anyone else that will run the program will not need the dll files on his pc and if he does need them so to have them in the directory where you are running the program from will be enough. How can i solve it ?

Also my brother tried to put the dll's in where he running the program from.

The 3 dll files are:

```
Microsoft.DirectX.Direct3D.DLL, Microsoft.DirectX.Direct3DX.DLL, Microsoft.DirectX.DLL
```

The question is why he is getting this exception ? Realy it dosent see/find the dll files ? Or maybe his machine not supporting this directx files ? Strange.

Another thing when i put my mouse on the hard disk on the dll files i see a baloon tip say the:

File description: Microsoft Managed Direct3D Debug

Maybe the problem is that the dll files of the directx belong to the debug directory but i make my program to be build in the release directory ?

In any case i can't find any solution yet. This is the exception message:

```
    System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.DirectX.Direct3DX.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.
File name: 'Microsoft.DirectX.Direct3DX.dll'
   at mws.ScanningClouds.InitializeDirectX()
   at mws.ScanningClouds.ScanClouds_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in d:\C-Sharp\Download File\Downloading-File-Project-Version-012\Downloading File\ScanningClouds.cs:line 142
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnCreateControl()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

This is the code the line where the exception happen 142:

```
private void ScanClouds_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Boolean bl = InitializeDirectX();

            if (bl == false)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error initializing directX!");
                Application.Exit();
            }
        }
```

The line is: `Boolean bl = InitializeDirectX();`
And the method: `InitializeDirectX()`

```
private Boolean InitializeDirectX()
        {
            DispMode = Manager.Adapters[Manager.Adapters.Default.Adapter].CurrentDisplayMode;
            D3Dpp = new PresentParameters();
            D3Dpp.BackBufferFormat = DispMode.Format;
            D3Dpp.PresentFlag = PresentFlag.LockableBackBuffer;

            D3Dpp.SwapEffect = SwapEffect.Discard;
            D3Dpp.PresentationInterval = PresentInterval.One; //wait for vertical sync. Synchronizes the painting with
            //monitor refresh rate for smoooth animation
            D3Dpp.Windowed = true; //the application has borders

            try
            {
                D3Ddev = new Device(Manager.Adapters.Default.Adapter, DeviceType.Hardware, pictureBox1.Handle,
                                                                           CreateFlags.SoftwareVertexProcessing, D3Dpp);
                D3Ddev.VertexFormat = CustomVertex.PositionColored.Format;
                D3Ddev.RenderState.Lighting = false;
                D3Ddev.RenderState.CullMode = Cull.CounterClockwise;

                //load imagesBmp to panelTexture
                //panelTexture = Texture.FromBitmap(D3Ddev, imagesBmp, Usage.Dynamic, Pool.Default)

                backTexture = TextureLoader.FromStream(D3Ddev, mymem);

                //scannerTexture = TextureLoader.FromFile(D3Ddev, @"D:\Buttons\Radar\radar.png");
                scannedCloudsTexture = new Texture(D3Ddev, 512, 512, 1, Usage.Dynamic, Format.A8R8G8B8, Pool.Default);

                //sprite is used to draw the texture
                D3Dsprite = new Sprite(D3Ddev);

                return true;
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: I can't figure out why my brother get the exception on this dll file/s while it's working fine on my pc.

Comment: As exception says alredy, 
 System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.DirectX.Direct3DX.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.
File name: 'Microsoft.DirectX.Direct3DX.dll'

Comment: *"or one of its dependencies"* - is the key, you need much more (more dlls) to have it working. Simplest solution is to install directX (search for "directX redist") on your bro  PC.

Comment: select the dll in reference folder. go to properties. set copy local to true.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Tell your brother to install the DX SDK or on windows 8 the windows SDK. 
This assembly does not belong in your application folder it's part of a set of libraries that are built around the windows API, and these assemblies have a set of complex relationships to other files that work to deliver DX on your PC.

EDIT: Since this answer was not considered "good enough" I thought I would elaborate a little ...

The files needed are part of the deep chain of dependencies your code has, by adding an installer project to your solution and building that the windows installation framework will highlight what's missing and prompt your brother to install the right parts whilst installing your DX application.

It should, kick of these installs automatically after saying something like "this thing depends on foo which is not installed, would you like to install it now?"

Assuming your brother answers yes ... problem solved!

Either, my original answer stands, installing the SDK would most likely solve the problem and these days most gamers have it installed on their pc's anyway.